# How to register multiple instances of same class

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dependency-injection, autofac

I am trying to register two instances of the same class but both instances end up share the same parameter values.

I have registered the following in my startup.cs:

```
using Autofac;
using Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
 public void ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
// Preferences
        builder.RegisterType<PreferencesRetriever>().As<IPreferencesRetriever>().SingleInstance()
            .WithParameter("collection", _configureMongo(_mongoUrl, MONGODB_PREFERENCES_COLLECTION))
            .Keyed<IPreferencesRetriever>("PreferencesRetriever");
// System Preferences
        builder.RegisterType<PreferencesRetriever>().As<IPreferencesRetriever>().SingleInstance()
            .WithParameter("collection", _configureMongo(_mongoUrl, MONGODB_SYSTEM_PREFERENCES_COLLECTION))
            .Keyed<IPreferencesRetriever>("SystemPreferencesRetriever");
    }
```

And have set up two controllers below:

```
using Autofac.Features.AttributeFilters;
public class PreferencesController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IPreferencesRetriever _preferencesRetriever;

    private readonly ILogger<PreferencesController> _logger;

    public PreferencesController(
        [KeyFilter("PreferencesRetriever")] IPreferencesRetriever preferencesRetriever,
        ILogger<PreferencesController> logger)
    {
        _preferencesRetriever = preferencesRetriever;
        _logger = logger;
    }
...
}
```

```
using Autofac.Features.AttributeFilters;
public class SystemPreferencesController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IPreferencesRetriever _preferencesRetriever;

    private readonly ILogger<PreferencesController> _logger;

    public SystemPreferencesController(
        [KeyFilter("SystemPreferencesRetriever")] IPreferencesRetriever preferencesRetriever,
        ILogger<PreferencesController> logger)
    {
        _preferencesRetriever = preferencesRetriever;
        _logger = logger;
    }
...
}
```

For whatever reason, both controllers end up using the `MONGODB_SYSTEM_PREFERENCES_COLLECTION` value.

Please let me know if I am missing something here.
I am happy to answer any questions.

Comment: Please re-read the [mre] guidance and make sure you provide enough information to reproduce the issue. I.e. I don't believe default .Net core DI container supports such registrations - it is possible you are using autofac or some custom code to support such registrations.

Comment: Yes I am using autofac

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable `.WithAttributeFiltering()` on `SystemPreferencesController` and `PreferencesController`.

Based on the [documentation](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/metadata.html#keyfilterattribute).

Comment: Sadly this didn't work. Same result as before

Comment: Please include the code in the post.

Comment: You'd also [need to add controllers as services](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html#controllers-as-services).

Answer (score 0):

in your `ConfigureContainer()`, add these 2 lines at bottom

```
builder.RegisterType<PreferencesController>().PropertiesAutowired().WithAttributeFiltering();  
builder.RegisterType<SystemPreferencesController>().PropertiesAutowired().WithAttributeFiltering();
```

I hope, it can help.
Have a good day.